# How can I make an if-statement based on what has randomly been printed?

Tags: python, if-statement, random, numbers

so I am creating a type of game that will involve dices. What I plan on doing is to have different things happening depending on what the player throws, it will be a 2 player game.

What I want to do is make the computer randomly generate 2 of the 6 possible dice sides. After that has been printed, the computer will move onto an if-statement where it will see ex: if a dice_1 and a dice_3 has been printed, the computer will do something. If it has printed a 1 and a 1, it will do another thing and so on.

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
for x in range(2):
  print random.randint(1,7)
```

So basically, to repeat what I need is a way to use the if-statement to check if the random numbers are ex: 1 and 3 & another example is to check if the numbers add up to 6.

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you try writing it out? have you made an attempt so far?

Comment: you can assign the result of a random roll to a variable like so: `result1 = random.randint(1,7)`. Then you can check eg. `if result1 == 6` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to read what you just printed, I would consider it more elegant to assign the two 'throws' to two variables, print out those two values, and then work with these two variables. For example:

```
import random
dice1 = random.randint(1,7)
dice2 = random.randint(1,7)
print(dice1, dice2)
if (dice1 + dice2 == 2): //do something
if (dice1 + dice2 == 3): //do something else 
//... and so on...
//or use switch-case
```

Comment: I don't think that `if` condition will ever be true… ;)

Comment: Thanks, so far it is working for what I intend on doing!